# How can I use pyEX to get earnings data for multiple periods?

Tags: python, elixir-iex

The documentation says you can get data for the four most recent earnings reports, but when I used the code below, it only returned data for one period.  How can I get the data for four periods?

```py
import pyEX as p
p.stocks.earningsDF('FB', token='myAPIToken', version='v1', filter='')
```

The output is below:

```
{'symbol': 'FB',
 'earnings': [{'actualEPS': 2.12,
   'consensusEPS': 1.91,
   'announceTime': 'AMC',
   'numberOfEstimates': 42,
   'EPSSurpriseDollar': 0.21,
   'EPSReportDate': '2019-10-30',
   'fiscalPeriod': 'Q3 2019',
   'fiscalEndDate': '2019-09-30',
   'yearAgo': 1.76,
   'yearAgoChangePercent': 0.2045}]}
```

Comment: Did you already check out the `filter` documentation at https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#filter-results?

Comment: It describes how to further filter the returned results (i.e. return only the EPSReportDate) but I can't find anything about getting the earnings data for previous earnings periods.